# No richtextbox control in WinRT (8.1)?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Was hoping code lines like this will work on WinRT:

```
<!--A RichTextBox with hyperlink.-->
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
    <Paragraph>
        Displaying text with <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.msdn.com" TargetName="_blank">hyperlink</Hyperlink>.
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

The end result I'm looking for is to turn this:

Hey @Jake

to this:
Hey **Jake Dawson**, how are you.

Once the user hits space after the @word.

Comment: Could you add the code for the keyboard handling to your question? It's not clear where you're stuck since you haven't provided any of the code. I'm not sure how the XAML you included is relevant to the problem at all. It seems like you'll need to track the `@` key press, and then space bar ... and do a text range substitution of some sort. There are lots of edge cases that you'll need to consider though, so it's not a trivial amount of code to do completely.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to set it to `IsReadonly="True"`, why don't you use a `RichTextBlock`?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227565

If you are only after the ability to include a hyperlink, you can do that in a regular TextBlock as well (in Windows 8.1), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.hyperlink.aspx

UPDATE:

After your clarification of the question, it seems that you do need an editing capability. Look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx

Comment: The IsReadOnly is set to false when the TextBox is focus so it can edit hyperlinks.  Essentially I really don't care for that property.  I kind of want a Text Box where the user types "@" and it shows his contacts.  When he selects one it turns to something like this:

Comment: @Jake Da => Jake Dawson (But in hyperlink form)

Comment: Ok, I try playing with it but this is really hard.  Say I know index 10 to 15 is supposed to be a hyperlink.  How can I do that?

Comment: Learn RTF. An easy way to do that is to use Windows Write to type and save RTF documents, and then open them in Notepad.